# Validation Error makes it impossible to interact with the page

Tags: javascript, validation, bootstrap-modal

I have a form which contains some field but when i submit it without entering any data(empty) it provides a phone validation error off to the side with a dark overlay, and it is then impossible to interact again with the page. I want the user to see the message and he should be able to interact with the page too.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13ltH.png)

```
/**
 * Checks the phone number field validity. Shows a modal popup if the format is not correct.
 */
$(document).ready(function() {
  var form_submitted = false;

  $('#save_form').click(function() {
    if (form_submitted) {
      alert('Your quiz submission is being processed. Sometimes this can take up to a minute. Please be patient while you are redirected to your results page.');
      return false;
    }

    var phone = $('#telefon').val();
    var location = $('#state').val();

    var matching_string = /^(([0]{2})?[\+]?[1]( |-)?)?(\(?[0-9]{3}\)?|[0-9]{3})?( |-)?([0-9]{3}( |-)?[0-9]{4})$/;
    var phone_match = matching_string.test(phone.trim());

    if (phone == '') {
      $('#basic-modal-content').html('<h3 class="ess_error">Validation Check</h3><p>Phone number cannot be blank.</p>');
      $('#basic-modal-content').modal();
      return false;
    } else {
      /*Added an additional check for the NON US customers. Phone number validation will only happen for US customers. 52 being the primary key for NON US in state table*/
      if (location != 52) {
        if (phone_match) {
          // TODO: Uncomment
          //$('#save_form').css("background", "url(/images/bodytypequiz/BTN-BTQ-TestResults-Processing.png) no-repeat");
          // TODO: Comment out below two lines
          $('#save_form').html('<img src="/images/bodytypequiz/BTQ-OptInSlide-SubmitButtonSubmitMessage-v1.0.png">');
          $('#save_form').css("left", "78px").css("width", "350px");
          form_submitted = true;
          $('#save').submit();
        } else {
          $('#basic-modal-content').html('<h3 class="ess_error">Validation Check</h3><p>Please enter a valid US phone number.</p>');
          $('#basic-modal-content').modal();
          return false;
        }
      } else {
        // TODO: Uncomment
        //$('#save_form').css("background", "url(/images/bodytypequiz/BTN-BTQ-TestResults-Processing.png) no-repeat");
        // TODO: Comment out below two lines
        $('#save_form').html('<img src="/images/bodytypequiz/BTQ-OptInSlide-SubmitButtonSubmitMessage-v1.0.png">');
        $('#save_form').css("left", "78px").css("width", "350px");
        form_submitted = true;
        $('#save').submit();
      }
    }
  });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
        <?php echo form_tag(url_for('@bodytype_quiz_save'), 'id=save') ?>
        <?php /* <div class="form-group form-inline">
          <label for="age" >In what age range do you fall into?<em class="required">*</em></label>
          <?php echo select_tag('age', options_for_select($age_aria, $form_vars['age']), array('class' => 'form-control')) ?>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
          <?php echo radiobutton_tag('sex[]', 1, $form_vars['male']) ?> <label for="sex_1_1">Male</label>
          <?php echo radiobutton_tag('sex[]', 2, $form_vars['female']) ?> <label for="sex_2_2">Female</label>
          </div> */ ?>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="comm">What main struggle are you having with your body now?</label>
          <textarea cols="40" rows="4" id="comm" name="comm" class="form-control"><?php echo $form_vars['comm'] ?></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group form-inline">
          <label for="age">What age did you start gaining? <em class="required">*</em></label>
          <?php echo select_tag('age', options_for_select($age_aria, $form_vars['age']), array('class' => 'form-control')) ?>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group form-inline">
          <label for="state">Which state do you live in? <em class="required">*</em></label>
          <?php echo select_tag('state', options_for_select($st_aria, $form_vars['state']), array('class' => 'form-control')) ?>
        </div>
        <table class="btq-table">
          <tr>
            <td width="22%">
              <label>Name: <em class="required">*</em></label>
            </td>
            <td width="58%">
              <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="<?php echo $form_vars['name'] ?>" class="form-control" />
            </td>
            <td width="20%">
              <span class="text-tertiary">Kept Private</span>          
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>
              <label>Email: <em class="required">*</em></label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $form_vars['email'] ?>" class="form-control" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <span class="text-tertiary">Kept Private</span>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>
              <label>Cell Phone: <em class="required">*</em></label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input required type="text" name="telefon" id="telefon" value="<?php echo $form_vars['telefon'] ?>" class="form-control" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <span class="text-tertiary">Kept Private</span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <?php if($error == 1): ?>
        <p><b id="wait" class="red">Some or all of the required fields are empty.</b></p>
        <?php endif;?>
        <div class="form-group text-center">
          <!--<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-tertiary btn-lg" value="ANALYZE" />-->
          <div id="save_form" class="Cursor-pointer" style="background:url(/images/bodytypequiz/BTN-BTQ-TestResults.png) center center;width:320px;height:44px;margin:0 auto;">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
        <h3 class="heading-tertiary">Find Out Your Primary Body Type Now!</h3>
        <div class="thumbnail mb-lg">
          <iframe width="100%" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $video_id ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <h3 class="heading-tertiary mt-md">Which ONE Is Your Primary Type ?</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
      <div class="text-center mt-lg">
        <small>
          We never give away your email, phone or personal information.<br />
          We'll send you some tips. By proceeding, you agree to our 
          <a href="<?php echo url_for('terms/tacpopup'); ?>" target="_blank">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>
          and <a href="<?php echo url_for('terms/polpopu'); ?>" target="_blank">Privacy Policy</a>.
        </small>
      </div>
      <?php else: ?>
      <div class="text-center">
        <div class="thumbnail col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
          <!--https://youtube.com/embed/ifaCNwzy0gI?autoplay=1-->
          <iframe width="100%" height="315" src="https://youtube.com/embed/ifaCNwzy0gI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 text-center col-md-offset-1">
        <h1 class="text-warning text-bold">FREE Adrenal Body Type <br />REPORT</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 text-center col-md-offset-0">
        <a href='javascript://' data-opf-trigger='p2c12528f12' id="open_popup_lnk" class="btn btn-warning btn-block btn-lg text-size-32 text-bold">
          <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> View PDF
        </a>
        <script type='text/javascript' async='true' src='https://app.ontraport.com/js/ontraport/opt_assets/drivers/opf.js' data-opf-uid='p2c12528f12' data-opf-params='borderColor=#fff&borderSize=20px&formHeight=552&formWidth=80%&popPosition=mc&instance=686239622'></script>
      </div>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="basic-modal-content"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem looks to be that you're opening an empty modal window over top your page with the `$('#basic-modal-content').modal();` call. If you inspect element on the page, I bet you'll discover there's a giant div over top everything.

Comment: So should i remove this line?

Comment: If you want the validation errors to show in a modal, no. The CSS on the modal content isn't loading inside it correctly. In your screenshot it's showing at the bottom of the page. My guess is the red button in the top right will close the modal or something?